# scenarioContext.TestError is null, but need to be not null

Tags: c#, specflow

language: C#
Testing:Specflow

I am getting `scenarioContext.TestError==null`,even when my scenarios are failing.
it is not initializing my `scenarioContext.TestErro`r and because of that I cannot attach screenshots of failing scenarios in expected folder, which also not giving right LivingDoc Report

I tried to clean, rebuild, build the project
I have tried to Unload/Reload the project
I have tried to Uninstall/Install "Specflow for Visual Studio Extension"

```
public class Hooks{
 [Binding]
    public class Hooks: CommonMethods
    {
        public IPage Driver { get; set; } = null!;
        public IBrowserContext context;
        public static int numberOfFailedTests;
        private ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;
        
        
        public Hooks( ScenarioContext scenarioContext )
        {
            this._scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
        }


    [AfterScenario]
        public async Task AfterScenario()
        {
            string uniqueString = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            uniqueString = uniqueString.Replace("/", "");
            uniqueString = uniqueString.Replace(" ", "");
            uniqueString = uniqueString.Replace(":", "");


            if (_scenarioContext.TestError != null)
            {
                numberOfFailedTests++;
                await context.Tracing.StopAsync(new()
                {
                    Path = $"{_scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title}_{numberOfFailedTests}_trace.zip"
                });

                await Driver.ScreenshotAsync(new()
                {
                    Path = CommonMethods.GetCurrentProjectDirectory() + "Screenshot\\Failed\\" + uniqueString + $"{_scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title}.png",
                    FullPage = true
                });
            }
}



public class Steps{

   [Binding]
    public class AmazonDashboardStepDefinitions : CommonMethods
    {
        private readonly IPage _page;
        private readonly AmazonDashboardPage _amazonDashboardPage;
        private ISpecFlowOutputHelper _specflowOutPutHelper;
        private ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;
        


        public AmazonDashboardStepDefinitions(Hooks hooks, ISpecFlowOutputHelper specFlowOutputHelper, ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
        {
            _page = hooks.Driver;
            _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
            _amazonDashboardPage =new AmazonDashboardPage(hooks, specFlowOutputHelper);
            _specflowOutPutHelper = specFlowOutputHelper;
        }


}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error message and stack trace.